# Calculated Column Based off of a Date & Time Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a field called "Onboarding Date" which is a Date & Time field.

I want to create a new field called "RetentionDate" which will be a date 1 year later than the users input in the Onboarding Date column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new calculated column & use formula in below format:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Onboarding Date]) + 1, MONTH([Onboarding Date]), DAY([Onboarding Date]))
```

**Documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas - Date and time formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#date-and-time-formulas)

**Note**: Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).